# Testing if Kafka topic is setup correctly

Tags: apache-kafka

Our applications uses various types of queues. Every time before starting the application that uses queues there is an automated pre-check happens that writes sample message(s) into required queues and read (i.e., deleting) it to confirm if the queue is set up properly.

Now we also use Kafka. But in Kafka we cannot do pre-check by writing and reading messages with Topics, because the messages cannot be deleted before starting the actual application which is kind of "polluting" the topic. Is there any other automated way, APIs or command-line scripts to do that in Kafka? Preferable in java or shell scripts.

Kafka version 0.11.x

Answer (score 2):

A `kafka-topics --describe --topic YOUR_TOPIC --zookeeper YOUR_ZK` should be sufficient. If there's output with active replicas that are in sync, you should be good to go. An alternative tool is [kafkacat](https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat) if the built-in tooling doesn't provide what you need (i.e. you can't/don't want to access ZooKeeper).